# Python: for loop does not perceive updated list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

the for loop in the function point() does not consider that the points list has been updated in the game() function. How can i solve that problem, so the result is the names_points list with updated values.

```
names = ["peter", "sofia", "reinhard", "leo"]

points = [10] * (len(list))

def point(points):
    for i in range(0, len(points)):
        names_points = [name + " has " + str(points[i]) + " points." for name in names]
    return names_points


def game():
    x = points[0] - 1
    points.remove(points[0])
    points.insert(0, x)
    return point(points)

print(game())
```

Comment: Note that you are overiding the value of `names_points` on each iteration of your loop. I believe what you are looking for is to `append` to the `names_points` list. So something like `names_points.append([name + " has " +...])`

Comment: you also use points as argument in your point function. Meaning, you don't mutate the global points variable but a local one that overshadows the global one.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it? What are you expecting to see instead?

Comment: @TheFool. But he's passing it around

Comment: yes right. sorry

Comment: I recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to return a list of strings that describe each player's name and how much points they currently have.

The problem with your code is not that it doesn't perceive the updated list, it is that it creates a new list on each iteration of the for loop that iterates over `points` list. This list overrides `names_point` with a new list, which is made of all the player's names and the score of the current `points[i]`.

To fix the first problem, you can either fix your list comprehension using `zip` like this:

```
names_point = [name + " has " + str(player_points) + " points." for name, player_points in zip(names, points)]
```

Thus eliminating the second problem as well. If you don't wish to use list comprehension you can instead use `points[i]` and `append` to aggregate strings into names_point in the following manner:

```
names_points = []
for i in range(len(points)):
        names_points.append(names[i] + " has " + str(points[i]) + " points.")
```